# Angular2 routing based on subdomain?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to route in Angular2 Router based on the subdomain in a URL.  For example if someone requests test.domain.com then they get the "test" route.  I could not get router.navigate to work from ngOnInit without setting a timeout delay, but running the following from the constructor works.  Would be interested if there was a cleaner solution ?

```
{path: 'test',                    component: TestComponent}

this._router.events.subscribe(event => {
 if (event.constructor.name === 'NavigationEnd'
     && window.location.hostname == 'test.domain.com'
     && event.url == '/') {
       console.log(event.url);
       this._router.navigate(['test']);
     }
 });
```

Comment: is it not working?

Comment: Routing is working in the app, but not from ngOnInit.

Answer (score 7):

You can't do this by Nginx or domain proxy, or by Ingres, etc.

To solve this case you can use different global routes and insert them to routingModule by the condition of the current domain is loaded code bundle:

You will solve problem with duplicates of code, double applications, but only another model of routing with existing components inside one app.

```
// app.routing.ts

const TEST_routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: TestPageComponent,
  },
];

const PROJECT_routes: Routes = [
  {
    /// all needed routes of the whole main project
  },
];

const isCurrentDomainTest: boolean =
(window.location.hostname === 'test.localhost') || // local
(window.location.hostname === 'test.yourdomain.com'); // prod

 imports: [
   RouterModule.forRoot(
    isCurrentDomainTest ? TEST_routes : PROJECT_routes)
]
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use **Guards** to prevent navigation or redirect to another path.
Similar to your example:

```
@Injectable()
export class RedirectGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(router:Router){}

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        // check if need redirect
        if (...) {
            console.log(`requested url: ${state.url}`);
            this.router.navigate(['/test']);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

To apply the guard you should add it to module providers and to configure Route:

```
[{
    path: '',
    component: YourComponent,
    canActivate: [RedirectGuard],  
    children... 
},
{
    path: 'test',
    component: YourTestComponent,
    children...
},
...
]
```

https://angular.io/guide/router#canactivatechild-guarding-child-routes

Also I suppose that you could configure your application with different **base href**:

```
let useTestSubdomain: boolean = window.location.hostname == 'test.domain.com';

@NgModule({
  providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: useTestSubdomain ? '/test' : '/'}]
})
class AppModule {}
```

https://angular.io/api/common/APP_BASE_HREF

Answer (score 1):

You can use **setTimeout** as shown here,

```
ngOnInit() {
    if (window.location.hostname == 'test.domain.com'){
      console.log(window.location.hostname);

      setTimeout(()=>{
         this._router.navigate(['test']);
      },2000)


    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Yes, works with setTimeout.  I'll do a bit more research to see if there is another way to delay navigation until Router is initialised.

Comment: AFAIK you don't have any other options but still check and update me for the same.

Comment: There may be a Router event associated with initialisation, so it may be possible to use that event to trigger the navigation.

Comment: Router event NavigationEnd is a bit cleaner, but still not great.

Comment: It will just give you that where you are redirecting to along with state.