# Angular 2 Routing Behaviour based on the domain

Tags: angular, proxy, routes, content-management-system

I am building a multi level CMS and trying to figure out a logic on the following.

I will have one application running and have multiple domains pointing to it. It can be absolute path or relative path with the client id for example these type of domain can be pointing:

1. www.wuhuuu.com ( Full URL pointing)
2. www.awesomeapp.com/**yaboo** ( our url + /ClientID 3)
3. bamboo.awesomeapp.com ( subdomain pointing to us)

**How do I tell my angular app what domain is getting accessed so that I can render a specific view?**

I've found out that you can pass routing from the DB via **resetConfig**.

```
router.resetConfig([
 { path: 'team/:id', component: TeamCmp, children: [
   { path: 'simple', component: SimpleCmp },
   { path: 'user/:name', component: UserCmp }
 ] }
]);
```

Comment: If i can understand the situation , your domains are multiple , Angular app is 1 . 
domain1 = angularapp's url + '/view1'
Am i correct ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question, but you can read about routing in the official documentation here :https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: @GiliYaniv Thanks, but it would be great it the documentation would be written better, but doesn't have what i need.

Comment: @AakashUniyal  I will have multiple domains and 1 app - correct.

Comment: @ChrisTarasovs can you explain again what are you trying to do? define routes for your app with dynamic parameters?

Comment: You can set different global routes due to the current domain. Hope it helps ->  https://stackoverflow.com/a/59784694/9026103

Answer (score -1):

If i understand your problem correctly then creating multiple routes for the respective domains in your angular app to load a component/module and in turn its views should be enough.

Example : 
Angular App's URL = "www.xyz.com"

Your angular app would have following routes :

`{ path: 'domain1', component: Domain1Component, children: DOMAIN1_ROUTES }`

`{ path: 'domain2', component: Domain2Component, children: DOMAIN2_ROUTES }`

`{ path: 'domain3', component: Domain3Component, children: DOMAIN3_ROUTES }`

`{ path: 'domain4', component: Domain4Component, children: DOMAIN4_ROUTES }`

And your domains would be pointing to the following URL :

Domains are internally pointed to your server hosting your angular app

`Domain 1 ----- > www.xyz.com/domain1`

`Domain 2 ----- > www.xyz.com/domain2`

`Domain 3 ----- > www.xyz.com/domain3`

`Domain 4 ----- > www.xyz.com/domain4`

Above implementation separates domains in angular based on component , it can be made better by separating them as modules

Do let me know if this answer is not enough , i would edit.

Comment: This does not solve the problem when there is a single route with multiple different DNS entries pointing to the app as described in the OPs question, this is something I am looking into achieving myself but the above does not solve the problem