# Choose between Routes depending on domain - Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-routing

Is it possible to choose between different route variables on app.module or app.routes ?
My problem is that I have different routes based on the application language,
if the application is called from `example.it` the routes should be in italian language and if it called by `example.fr` in french.
Below is the approach I am trying to put to work but I cant find a way to choose the right export:

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { fr, it } from "@providers/routes.provider";

const availableRoutes: any = {
    "it": it,
    "fr": fr
};

const lang = "it"; // this should be dynamic somehow so this would work correctly

export const appRoutes: Routes = availableRoutes[lang];
```

Comment: I hope it helps you - it's my solution with two domains and one angular app but with different routes - https://stackoverflow.com/a/59784694/9026103. But on prod - check first if `window.location` works properly

Answer (score 0):

You can write a separate proxy component that redirects the user based on certain conditions like so:

In your `routing module`:

```
{
    path: "",
    component: ProxyComponent,
    children: [
        {path: "**", component: ProcessProxyComponent},
    ]
}
```

And then in `ProcessProxyComponent`:

```
...

constructor(...) {
    if(lang === "it") {
        router.navigate(...);
    }
}

...
```