# Multiple domains and subdomains using one Angular 7 app

Tags: node.js, angular, nginx

I have an idea for a website that I want to build myself. I have been reading in the documentation, in articles and through tutorials. But I couldn’t fully find the answers I needed.

**Situation:**

I have a project at AWS Lightsail (including: Angular 7, Node, MongoDB, Nginx, Express). I have multiple domain names with dynamic subdomains, used to differentiate information for employees of clients/brands. The multiple domains are part of it to make it easier to navigate and communicate.

For example:

```
client1.domain1.com/some/info/
client1.domain2.com/some/info/
..etc.
```

**Setup:**

I have configured the subdomains and domains through **Nginx** making it work with wildcard subdomains as well as declared subdomains and domains. The dynamic subdomains are configured like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name ~^((?<sub>.*)\.)(?<domain>[^.]+)\.com$;
  root /opt/bitnami/nginx/html/$domain/$sub;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html$is_args$args;
}
```

which outputs as this directory:

```
/opt/bitnami/nginx/html/domain1/client1/
```

*(client1 is in there just to test. It wouldn’t be a directory in an ideal case. Also domain1 & client1 should only be in the url as the domain & subdomain itself. not as a directory)*

**Thoughts:**

Ideally it would be one system where each domain points to, and the content is differentiated based on the domain name and client. I thought about the following:

- Have a separate app on each domain. But that would give a lot of duplicate code and work to maintain/do changes.
- Have a component for each domain. But then I don’t know how to make the routing work.
- Have multiple apps in one project. But Angular deploys everything in 1 HTML file with JavaScript. How do I make the routing work there?
- etc.

But none really seem to work as I imagine. How do I make this work properly? How would I be able to serve the app using multiple domains in a valid, scalable & secure way?

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use a single application with multiple domain bindings and then use routing within the app to segregate content.  Assuming no client specific secure information is hard coded into the angular app, you should be able to create a secure application using Angular Routeing paired with a web api to make the end result you are describing.

client1.domain1.com/client/1/info/
client1.domain2.com/client/2/info/

clientx.domainx.com -> all resolve to your app

/client/ -> routes to an angular component

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [ 
       { path: 'client/:id', component: dynamicClientComponent },
     ]
  }
];
```

In the angular client component you get your client ID from the url and retrieve client specific content from a web service/api

```
 constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private clientService: CientService,

  ) {
    route.params.subscribe(params => {
         this.id = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
         if (this.id) {
             this.clientService.getById(this.id).subscribe(
              (record) => {
                 this.ClientInfo = record;
                   //update UI accordingly

         })
    };
}
```

Here is a working example that illustrates this better than my code excerpt
https://stackblitz.com/edit/router-pillar1-demo-final?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: Hi Ali, Thank you for your response! I understand what you mean and yes I'm trying to configure everything so it uses 1 single app and using an API. Your answer seems to more focus on passing variables in the router path and displaying it instead of connecting the domains. I would like to **exclude** client/:id from the URL. Also your answer doesn't seem to differentiate between the domains. How would this be done since angular uses the path, not the full URL to route.

Comment: I guess I assumed obtaining the client identifier from the domain wasn't critical for you to meet your objective.  I thought it would be sufficient to have client specific domains to give the client the look and feel of a devoted application, but then you could redundantly include the client in the path in order to obtain it from the route or the use Location.path if you don't really need to use routing in your app.

Comment: cont..... If you must get identifier from the domain, you could inject the window object to obtain the hostname, but in my opinion I think this architecture could be more trouble than it's worth.  Remember that window does not exist at build time.  Think about how this configuration would affect testing scenarios and your AOT build process.  But maybe it's critical for you in which case it can be done

Comment: Yes, the client name and domain name would need to be taken from the domain since they differentiate the content being shown. This is because people navigate to client1.domain1.com/the/info directly. Is there another way besides getting it from the URL so the application would know which client and which domain it is at?

Comment: Not that I can speak to.  I'm sure there is some way to do it, but probably not worth the complexity over just accessing the window location in the angular app.  I guess one option would be to develop one set of dynamic source code with an build configration variable that would be set to the client ID and then plan to build and deploy for each client.  Then AOT build testing could use the same variable.  But this doesn't achieve your single-deployment goal.

Answer (score 0):

if you use different domains for different info you can use different routes and insert them due to current domain `location.hostname`. Hope it helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/59784694/9026103